# How can I make Alexa Intent handler respond with different things each time it is called?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to develop an Alexa Skill with ASK node.js SDK. I am trying to build a game where the Alexa and the user take turns counting (not a great game, but useful educationally for me). Alexa starts with one, then the user two, then Alexa says three, and so on until the user says an incorrect number. In this case, I hope to implement logic to end the game.I am struggling to figure out how to get Alexa to respond differently after each time the user says a number. Is this a situation where I need multiple intent handlers? It seems like that would be silly, as the general logic does not change. I'm struggling to find up to date example code of game logic generally, so any resources that I can learn from would be greatly appreciated. The code I have as of yet is as follows--

```
const MyGameIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
  && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'MyGameIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
const speechText = 'One';

return handlerInput.responseBuilder
  .speak(speechText).listen()
  .getResponse();
}
};
```

Obviously, I have not gotten very far. I have successfully created an intent and tested that Alexa will respond with 'One' when I ask to start a game. Where I am stuck is how to get Alexa to say 'One', then wait for a user to say 'Two', and depending on if they said the correct number, Alexa would say 'Three' or 'Game over' and end the game. The Codecademy course for ASK uses a different and outdated syntax, but it is the closest I have come yet to an answer. It suggests to chain a `.listen()` after speak, but does not provide information about whether this `.listen()` will re-prompt the same intent handler

Answer (score 0):

To make it work as you wish, you need to keep the state of the game in [Session Attributes](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/manage-skill-session-and-session-attributes.html) between utterances. Please read it to better understand how it works.

If about your game, I would suggest to follow those steps:

1. You speak "start the game", the skill responses with "One" (you have already implemented this part) AND stores the game state (ie. by saving next expected answer)
2. When it's your turn, the skill should check if received answer is equal to expected and react - continue and store next expected answer or finish the game. For this step you'll need another handler for intent which expects just a number.

There is an example from Alexa team that shows how to create a game and store the state between utterances - [Trivia Game](https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-trivia/blob/en-US/lambda/custom/index.js).